# Spotify Embed iFrame only plays previews of songs

Tags: angular, iframe, browser, spotify, angular-dom-sanitizer

On my website, I can only seem to play previews of the tracks in the playlist in Chrome and Safari even though I am logged in to Spotify Premium. However, the full tracks can be played in Firefox. Why might this be the case?

Here is my website : www.studify.online

Steps to reproduce:
Create an account and login
Click on "Music with background noise"
Select a playlist and play

Expected behaviour:
Widget is able to play full songs as user is logged in.

Actual behaviour:
Widget it only able to play previews of songs in Chrome and Safari.

Here is an example url that one of my playlists is using. https://open.spotify.com/embed?uri=spotify:user:1276120884:playlist:3lupJoO6PjahRjP3ehIUpq"

The entire track can be played in any browser when running on localhost, but cannot on heroku server.

My iFrame HTML is as follows:

```
<iframe *ngIf="playlistSelected" [src]="embedURI" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe><div class="dropdown">
```

My angular2 component that controls this iFrame is as follows:

```
onPlaylistSelect(playlist) {
    console.log(playlist);
    this.selected = playlist;
    this.embedURI = "https://open.spotify.com/embed?uri=" + this.selected.uri;
    this.embedURI = this.urlbypassPipe.transform(this.embedURI);
    console.log(this.embedURI);
    this.playlistSelected = true;
  }
```

This is my urlbyassPipe class:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'urlbypass'
})
export class UrlbypassPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }

}
```

Comment: Could this be because you can only play full songs on spotify if you pay for premium?

Comment: I am logged into my premium account

Comment: As of 2023 I get this same issue, except for me it shows the full song in Chrome, but not in Safari or Firefox.